# Cannot get search site to process 2 variables and output results accordingly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I cannot figure out how to get the code right to be able to select more than two cities for it to search and display two cities results. It does one at a time or everything in the database but not a selected number.

I will include some Select side code first below and right after that some of the processing page code. There is a third page of code as well which is the output code I think. If anyone needs to see that I can post that later. I'm not sure the solution needs to address that page but I might be wrong there.

```
 <form id="main-search-form" method="GET" action="<?= $baseurl; ?>/_searchresults6.php" role="search">


        <select id="query-input" name="city_id" style="width:28.8%" style="height:69px" required>

            <option value="">Select Area</option>

            <option value="3;1">Ches & VB</option>
            <option value="3">Chesapeake , VA</option>
            <option value="9">Hampton , VA</option> 
            <option value="10">Newport News , VA</option>           
            <option value="2">Norfolk , VA</option>         
            <option value="12">Poquoson , VA</option>   
            <option value="4">Portsmouth , VA</option>              
            <option value="5">Suffolk , VA</option>             
            <option value="1">Virginia Beach , VA</option>  
            <option value="11">Williamsburg , VA</option>
            <option value="0">All Active US Cities</option>



            </select>
                            </form>

//This next code is from the processing page//

<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/inc/config.php');
?>
<?php
$total_rows = 0;
$response = array();

$query_city_id = (!empty($_GET['city_id'])) ? $_GET['city_id'] : 0;
$query_query   = (!empty($_GET['query']))   ? $_GET['query']   : '';  
$page          = (!empty($_GET['page']))    ? $_GET['page']    : 1;

// check vars
if(!is_numeric($query_city_id)) {

}
$query_city_id = (int)$query_city_id;

// city details
$query_city_name  = '';
$query_state_abbr = '';



if (isset($_GET['city_id'])) {
    if ($_GET['city_id'] != 0) {
        $ids = explode(';', $_GET['city_id']) ;        // split multiple ids
        $k = count($ids);
        $placeholders = array_fill(0, $k, '?');
        $placestr = join(',', $placeholders);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT city_name, state FROM cities WHERE city_id IN ($placestr)");
        $stmt->execute($ids); 
    }
    else {
        // if you want all cities then a where clause is not needed
        $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT city_name, state FROM cities");        
    }
    // process the stmt results here
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $query_city_name = $row['city_name'];
    $query_state_abbr = $row['state'];
    echo "$query_city_name, $query_state_abbr<br>";
}
}


// paging vars
$limit = $items_per_page;
if($page > 1) {
    $offset = ($page-1) * $limit + 1;
}
else {
    $offset = 1;
}

// get page
if($page == 1) {
    $pag = '';
}
else {
    $pag = "- $txt_page $page";
}

// count total rows
if(!empty($query_city_id) && !empty($query_query)) {
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows
        FROM places
        WHERE city_id = :city_id AND status != 'trashed' AND paid = 1
            AND MATCH(place_name, description) AGAINST(:query) ";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':city_id', $query_city_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':query', $query_query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $total_rows = $row['total_rows'];
}
else if (empty($query_city_id) && !empty($query_query)) {
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows
        FROM places
        WHERE status != 'trashed' AND paid = 1
        AND MATCH(place_name, description) AGAINST(:query)";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':query', $query_query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $total_rows = $row['total_rows'];
}
else if (!empty($query_city_id) && empty($query_query)) {
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows
        FROM places
        WHERE status != 'trashed' AND paid = 1 AND city_id = :city_id";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':city_id', $query_city_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $total_rows = $row['total_rows'];
}
else {
    $total_rows = 0;
}

$pager = new DirectoryApp\PageIterator($limit, $total_rows, $page);
$start = $pager->getStartRow();

// initialize empty city and query check
$empty_city_and_query = false;

/*--------------------------------------------------
LIST ITEMS LOGIC
--------------------------------------------------*/
if(!empty($query_city_id) && !empty($query_query)) {
    $query = "SELECT p.place_id, p.place_name, p.address, p.cross_street,
                p.postal_code, p.phone, p.area_code, p.lat, p.lng, p.state_id, p.description,
                c.city_name, c.slug, c.state, ph.filename, ph.dir,
                rev_table.avg_rating
                FROM places p
                LEFT JOIN cities c ON p.city_id = c.city_id
                LEFT JOIN photos ph ON p.place_id = ph.place_id
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT *,
                        AVG(rev.rating) AS avg_rating
                        FROM reviews rev

                    ) rev_table ON p.place_id = rev_table.place_id
                WHERE p.city_id = :city_id AND p.status != 'trashed' AND paid = 1
                    AND MATCH(place_name, description) AGAINST(:query)

                LIMIT :start, :limit";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':city_id', $query_city_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':query', $query_query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':start', $start);
    $stmt->bindValue(':limit', $limit);
}

else if(empty($query_city_id) && !empty($query_query)) {
    $query = "SELECT p.place_id, p.place_name, p.address, p.cross_street,
                p.postal_code, p.phone, p.area_code, p.lat, p.lng, p.state_id, p.description,
                c.city_name, c.slug, c.state, ph.filename, ph.dir,
                rev_table.avg_rating
                FROM places p
                LEFT JOIN cities c ON p.city_id = c.city_id
                LEFT JOIN photos ph ON p.place_id = ph.place_id
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT *,
                        AVG(rev.rating) AS avg_rating
                        FROM reviews rev
                    ) rev_table ON p.place_id = rev_table.place_id
                WHERE p.status != 'trashed' AND paid = 1
                    AND MATCH(place_name, description) AGAINST(:query)

                LIMIT :start, :limit";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':query', $query_query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':start', $start);
    $stmt->bindValue(':limit', $limit);
}

else if(!empty($query_city_id) && empty($query_query)) {
    $query = "SELECT p.place_id, p.place_name, p.address, p.cross_street,
                p.postal_code, p.phone, p.area_code, p.lat, p.lng, p.state_id, p.description,
                c.city_name, c.slug, c.state, ph.filename, ph.dir,
                rev_table.avg_rating
                FROM places p
                LEFT JOIN cities c ON p.city_id = c.city_id
                LEFT JOIN photos ph ON p.place_id = ph.place_id
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT *,
                        AVG(rev.rating) AS avg_rating
                        FROM reviews rev

                    ) rev_table ON p.place_id = rev_table.place_id
                WHERE p.city_id = :city_id AND p.status != 'trashed' AND paid = 1

                LIMIT :start, :limit";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':city_id', $query_city_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':start', $start);
    $stmt->bindValue(':limit', $limit);
}

else{ // both $query_loc and $query_query empty
    $empty_city_and_query = true;
}

// now execute query
$stmt->execute();
```

I've put this up for solutions on other forums and nobody has the answer that fixes it yet. It could be that I'm missing something but that's the latest code changes... Need Help bad.

Comment: There are a number of issues with the handling and processing of the "Ches & VB" option. The select tag will need a `multiple` attribute if you are trying to allow users to select more than one option. The select name attribute should be `name="city_id[]"` to store multiple select values in an array

Comment: I just want the Ches & VB  which I have coded in the select option as 3;1 to work.  I don't want there to be a multiple attribute for users to select more than one option.  I see what you are saying about the name="city_id[]" and I've tried that but haven't been able to figure out what to do on the other code page that processes it.  What do I need to do there to make this work?

Comment: Whoever can help me get the code right for this to work I will pay and also put on company pay for whenever I need this kind of help.  


I have this multiple variable problem to solve 


and


I want to figure out also how to get the drop down to be auto populating where you type in 3 letter or so and it pulls up the city to search.  


The first one I want to solve first and then second one after.  


Let me know who wants to do this.

Comment: Do you need help with building a query using the locations from the array?

Comment: Yes I think that's what I need help with.  The site works perfectly except I want to be able to do the two variables at once shown on the site as "3;1" in the code.  See the site at:  https://localbizseek.com/lbs/index6